# Javascript querySelectorAll elements that have a parent element with specific class

Tags: javascript

let say I have:

```html
<div class = "testimonials-wrapper">
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>

<blockquote>...</blockquote>

<div class = "testimonials-wrapper">
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>
```

How can I select the `<blockquote>` elements, but only that are inside the `testimonials-wrapper`

tryed: `document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-wrapper .blocquote");` but no luck

Comment: document.querySelector("testimonials-wrapper").closest('blockquote')

Comment: @SaadSohail — `closest` searches **ancestors** not descendants and the selector `testimonials-wrapper` doesn't match anything

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for correction mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-wrapper blockquote")
```

This will only return all the `<blockquote>` elements, but only that are inside the `testimonials-wrapper` class.

```js
var blockquotes = document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-wrapper blockquote");
console.log( blockquotes.length )
```

```html
<div class = "testimonials-wrapper">
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>

<blockquote>...</blockquote>

<div class = "testimonials-wrapper">
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
   <blockquote>...</blockquote>
</div>
```

You can see in this demo `blockquotes.length` returned is `6` instead of `7` as it ignores the `<blockquote>` in the middle using this selector.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below query to get all the `blockquote`s inside `testimonials-wrapper` class

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".testimonials-wrapper blockquote")
```

Answer (score 1):

> All elements that have a parent element with specific class

OK, so "All elements" is the [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors):

```
*
```

"with a parent element" is the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

```
... > *
```

And "with specific class" is the [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors):

```
.testimonials-wrapper > *
```

---

> .testimonials-wrapper .blocquote

That selects descendants of `testimonials-wrapper` not children, you misspelt `blockquote`, and you used a class selector instead of a type selector.